# Why is apache refusing to start in Xampp?

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I've been trying to create a virtual host with the use of XAMPP and APACHE, however, when I go to boot up Apache in the XAMPP control panel it keeps showing up with errors. Why would this be happening? Have I missed something out or gotten something wrong?

My Virtual Host lines in Notepad ++:

[image: example]

Error message:

[image: example]

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask]. On top, this doesn't seem programming related (see [help/on-topic]) and there are better places for questions like this on the stackexchange network - e.g. superuser

Comment: Please check and post error_log. There not enough informations to help you: it might depend on your user (not being an administrator), a process already using the same port  or something else.